# Polynomial Splines vs Whittacker-Shannon Interpolation for uniform data

Tags: ho.history-overview, splines

> **Question:**
>
> (why) are polynomial splines preferred over [Whittacker-Shannon interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula)?
>
> Is it for genuine mathematical reasons like numeric stability and/or precision, or for other reasons?

Having massive parallel computing power at hand via GPUs, my impression is that Whittacker-Shannon interpolation may nowadays be an interesting alternative to classical spline interpolation in the case of uniformly spaced data.

Comment: I think the "Whittacker-Shannon interpolation" assumes the data generating function to be band limited.

Comment: @user102868 could you elaborate at that, e.g. by a set of data, that demonstrates superiority of spline interpolation? To me the  shiftet $sinc$ funktion seem quite analogous to Lagrange polynomials which have good numerical properties.

Comment: its not about superiority. Its about convergence to the generating function, as the data points become dense(meaning more and more data points). If the data generating function is not band limited to the appropriate frequency depending on the sinc function, there will be a phenomenon of aliasing. So Shannon Whittaker interpolation is generally used when the signal/function is obtained via uniform Nyquist sampling. (continued...)

Comment: Splines have no such restrictions, but still they need some other smoothness criterion for convergence. So over all, given a number of data points, We can't say which is superior unless there are questions asked about the convergence to generating function as the data becomes dense.

Comment: You may find this useful, if you haven't already read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Comment: @user102868 thanks for the nice explanation; so I guess it may be worth checking whether the outcome/appearance of the Whittaker Shannon interpolation is pleasing for specific situations, i.e. if aesthetics are better regarding extraneous wiggles.